ReactJS // I'm having trouble running website
USER@LAPTOP-TNN1KATN MINGW64 ~/Desktop/prescripto/frontend
$ npm run dev

frontend@0.0.0 dev
vite

X [ERROR] Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0:
  1 │ import.meta.dirname
    ╵ ~~~~~~

X [ERROR] Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0:
  1 │ import.meta.filename
    ╵ ~~~~~~

X [ERROR] Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0:
  1 │ import.meta.url
    ╵ ~~~~~~

failed to load config from C:\Users\USER\Desktop\prescripto\frontend\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: Build failed with 3 errors:
(define name):1:0: ERROR: Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0: ERROR: Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0: ERROR: Expected identifier but found "import"
at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\prescripto\frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1476:15)
at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\prescripto\frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:945:25
at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\prescripto\frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1316:45)
at buildResponseToResult (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\prescripto\frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:943:7)
at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\prescripto\frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:970:16
at responseCallbacks. (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\prescripto\frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:622:9)
at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\prescripto\frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:677:12)
at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\prescripto\frontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:600:7)
at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
I don't know how to fix it

Please don't create new account to ask the same question. Instead you should edit your original question so it's a good fit for StackOverflow - Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask]
